# setState doesn't work when I call it in function and give me Type Error (Reactjs)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have "stand alone function return obj when I call it inside another function in the component
then make setState  it gives me TypeError: "Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined"

this is the function

```
const formError = {
    name: '',
    email: '',
    password: ''
}

function getUserInfo(e) {
    const { name, value } = e.target

    // start paterns 
    const userNamePattern = /^[A-Za-z0-9_ ]{3,}/
    const emailPattern = /^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@(gmail|yahoo|hotmail).[a-z]{2,}$/
    const passwordPattern = /(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*\d).{6,}/
    //end patterns 

    if (name === 'name') {
        if (!value.match(userNamePattern)) {
            formError.name = ""
        } else
            formError.name = "correct name"

    }
    // here is same if condition for email and password too 

    return formError

}

export default getUserInfo
```

this function is part of component I call it onBlur event and inside it there is calling for the stand alone function above

```
handelCheckMatchValueOnBlur = (e) =>{
 const { name, value } = e.target

////function call
    const getFormError = getUserInfo(e)

    // element msg that will appere when user data not match the pattern

    const errorName = document.querySelector('#error-name')
    const errorEmail = document.querySelector('#error-email')
    const errorPassword = document.querySelector('#error-password')


    if (!getFormError.name)
      errorName.style.display = "block"

    if (getFormError.name) {
      errorName.style.display = "none"
      this.setState(prevState => {
        return {
          userInfo: { ...prevState.userInfo, [name]: value }
        }
      })
    }
// here is the same code for email and password too
}
```

this is the render on component

```
   render() {
    return (
      <section className="register" >
        <form onSubmit={this.handelSubmit}>
          <p>
            <input
              placeholder="Enter Your Name"
              type='text'
              name="name"
              onBlur={this.handelCheckMatchValueOnBlur}
              required
            />
          </p>
          <div id="error-name" role="alert">name must be at least 3 characters</div>

         ///// here the same input but for email and password

          <button disabled={!this.state.isValid}>submit</button>
        </form>
      </section>
    )

}
```

Comment: Where have you called `setState`? The question is not quite clear.

Comment: can you show the entire component

Comment: thanks, both for replying I edit the question  and  show the entire component   with the function that called setState

Comment: try making handelCheckMatchValueOnBlur as arrow fn?

Comment: Yeah! You are right it works with arrow fn, thank you so much